# URLs loop and jquery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to set $.get to check several urls instead of just one? And I presume I need loop for the urls - they're pretty much the same,  with a different number at the end.

- example.com/1
- example.com/2
- ...
- example.com/50

.

```
$.get(all urls from example.com/1 to example.com/50, do some stuff..)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=1; i<=50; i++){
   $.get("exaple.com/"+i ..................
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this is working, but not exactly as i wanted. I have an if else statement inside .get to open the result in a new window, and this is opening 50 new tabs with the results and i need just the one. How can I fix it?

Comment: @user2466444 by simply not opening new tabs. What you want to achieve? "one"... which one? Can you be more specific, I'm having hard time to read your mind :)

Comment: Find XXX in all urls and display it in a new tab.

Comment: @user2466444 wow, what is XXX ? Plese be more specific, either edit/improve your question. I answered your question as it currently states. Make sure to add more details immediately instead of asking sub-questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the `url`'s are in a `list` you can use

```
$('ul li a').each(function(){
 var link = $(this).attr('href');
...
 })
```

I chose `ul li a` but you can use whatever you want. If you have an `array` you can use

```
$.each(array, function() { .. });
```

instead. 
It depends on how you're `url`'s are ordinated.